# Functions are values, meaning?

Tags: javascript

I read this sentence, as trying to understand better anonymous functions.

> Because functions are values, you can pass a function as an argument into another function.

I can't grasp the "*functions are values*" idea.
If I had to define precisely what functions are, I would say functions *return* values, or *functions are blocks of code*. Or *function name is a value*.
What does it mean "functions are values"?

Thanks

Comment: Functions don't require names. They can also be assigned to a variable as a value. Functions can return a function (a value).

Comment: I think the best way to think of it is that you can put them on the right-hand side of an assignment. As in "a=b" and b can be any value - which can be a function. They also return values, and can indeed return functions.

Comment: It means functions are [first-class-citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) in javascript. You can treat them the same as e.g. a number or a string, in the way that you can pass them as arguments, store them to variables or properties, etc. They are "just another value you can store and read".

Comment: "*Or function name is a value.*" and what is the value of a function name? If you have `function foo() {}` what would `foo` be? Answer is it's *the function*. So, functions *are* values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = 1
```

The variable x has a value which is a primitive number 1.

```
var y = { foo: 1 };
```

The variable y has a value which is an object.

```
var z = function () { return 1; }
```

The variable z has a value which is a function.

And you can treat that function like any other value.

```js
var z = function () { return 1; }

var a = function (an_argument) {
    console.log("Log an_argument", an_argument);
    console.log("Call an_argument", an_argument());
}

a(z);
```

Comment: Ok so I have two states of a function: as a _potential_ and _executed_. "Function as a value" always falls in the first case right?

Comment: No. A function is always a function, which is a type of value. It can be called multiple times and it will return its return value. There is no "called function" and "uncalled function" state.

Comment: @Manaus when you call a function, you get its return result. You don't get the function back with a different state. Nor is the existing function changed by being called. A function is a value that can be *called*. As opposed to, say, a number or a string: `str = "hello"; str()` will fail because it's not callable.